# Fade out effect in Java 2d/AWT

Tags: java, fadeout

I would like to display an image for 6.5s in total and fade it out in the last 1.5s. I'm getting a NPE at line:

```
g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, transparency));
```

I read some, and I think it is because gameLogo is not a BufferedImage, just a simple Image. I made it with paint.net so it should have an alpha channel by default. I searched some forums about making BufferedImage but still confused.

The code snippet below worked perfectly before I added the extra lines to chage the last 1.5s.

Thank you for your help in advance!

EDIT:

with adding cast (Graphics2D) NPE if fixed but it still doesn't fade out totally...

Should I use
    offG.dispose();
somewhere?

```
offG.setColor(Color.BLACK);
offG.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 480);
counter += deltaTime;
// start fade out after 4 seconds
if (counter < 4000)
    offG.drawImage(devLogo, 0, 0, this);
else {
    transparency = (float)(1 - (counter - 4000) / 50 * 0.02);
    if (transparency < 0)
    transparency = 0;
    ((Graphics2D) offG).setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, transparency));
    offG.drawImage(devLogo, 0, 0, this);
}
// wait 6,5 seconds
if (counter > 6500) {
    gameState = 2;
    counter = 0;
    transparency = 1;
    ((Graphics2D) offG).setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, transparency));
}
```

Comment: Where does `g2d` come from?

Comment: `g2d` is probably null. Shouldnt it be e `offG` ??

Comment: @MadProgrammer private Graphics offG; private Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) offG;

Comment: Great, so you are castig `null` to `null` and later on only `offG` is initialized

Comment: I have edited my question as I still have some other problems. With adding cast (Graphics2D) NPE if fixed but it still doesn't fade out totally...

Should I use offG.dispose(); somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should provide more code for that. In you case `g2d` is `null`. According to your comment you are holding `Graphics` objects in fields. `Graphics` object is passed to the drawing method by AWT, and you probably assigning it to your field, but you forgot to assign new value to your `g2d` field as well.
I think there is no need to keep single object in 2 different typed fields. If I were you I would operate only on `Graphics2d` type object. That would put end to the confusion in your code that you have made. You are threating the same `Graphics` object as 2 separate entities but your fields referring to the same object. Why for? No need for that.

```
  ((Graphics2d)offG).setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, transparency));
```

and `NPE` is gone right?